# How can I use `\sort ...`?

Tags: perl, reference

I am wondering what `\sort ...` returns.

After executing the following line

```
my $y = \sort qw(one two three four five);
```

`$y` is a reference to a scalar. I actually expected a reference to an array: the array with the sorted elements (five, four, one, three, two). When dereferencing `$y` (for example `print $$y`), I get `two`, the last element of the sorted list.

Is there any useful thing I can to with `\sort(...)`?

Comment: See [perldata](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors):  `$foo = ('cc', '-E', $bar)` assigns the value of variable `$bar` to the scalar variable `$foo`

Comment: `my $y = [ sort ... ]`, OTOH, provides something far more useful.

Comment: @ikegami, as it happens... this is what I wanted in the first place...

Comment: The people who Answered assumed you knew that (because of the way you phrased your question). I just made sure :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sort` returns a list.

`\LIST` (like `\($x,$y,42)`) produces another list containing references to each element of the original list `(\$x,\$y,\42)`.

So `\sort ...` returns references to the elements of a sorted list.

Now in scalar context, `$foo = LIST` assigns the last element of the list. Putting this altogether,

```
my $y = \sort qw(one two three four five);
```

assigns a reference to the last sorted element to `$y`, or

```
print $$y;        # "two"
```

I can't think of any good use cases for this feature, but that is not very good evidence that one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 5):

According to [perldata](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#List-value-constructors) assigning a scalar to a list of values, assigns the last value of the list to the scalar. So

```
$foo = ('cc', '-E', $bar);
```

assigns the value of variable `$bar` to the scalar variable `$foo`.

According to [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html), 
taking a reference to an enumerated list is the same as creating a list of references. Hence,

```
my $y = \sort qw(one two three four five);
```

is equivalent to

```
my $y = \(sort qw(one two three four five));
```

which is equivalent to

```
 my $y = \(sort qw(one two three four five))[-1];
```

which will give a reference to the last value of the sorted list, i.e. the scalar value "two".

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Isn't this list context then `\( sort ... )` ?

Comment: Parentheses don't change anything. I deleted my comment because I realized ``\`` evaluates its operand in list context: `perl -MO=Concise -e'\sort'`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot Do you know if this behavior of `\\` (backslash) documented anywhere?

Comment: I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: perlref says "*Taking a reference to an enumerated list is not the same as using square brackets--instead it's the same as creating a list of references!*". By "enumerated list", it means `\(..., ..., ...)`. It mentions special-cases `\(@a)` and `\(%h)`, but it doesn't mention that this applies to all operators, not just "enumerated lists". Patches welcome :)